# AppIcon overlays with launch image

Tags: ios7, xcode5

I create a new iOS project in XCode 5. I choose to use asset catalog for both app icons & launch images. When I run the application, the app icon is overlayed on the launch image. How do I prevent this?

This is my app icon:

[image: AppIcon]

This is launch image:
[image: Launch Image]

I get this as the launch image on the simulator (and in device)

[image: launch image on simulator]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For those who come here searching, I solved this issue. The launch images should be opaque and not transparent.

I used iDraw to create the launch image. Instead of exporting the entire canvas, I selected 'all objects' which created a transparent image, which caused this issue.

Now it is solved and submitted to AppStore

Comment: Yes, and you should drag/select them once more in assets manager after adding background